# Terminate Function Execution from Instance Creation

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I try to stop the execution of a function by creating an Instance

**Basic Example**

```
class Foo {
    constructor(continueExec) {
    return continueExec;
  }
}

(() => {
    const guard = new Foo(false);
  console.log('hello');
})()
```

**My Use Case**

I'm using Express.js with Typescript and want top create a Guard class to use individually in server Routes

*Declaration*

```
class Guard {
    user;
    res;

    constructor(req?: any, res?:any) {
         this.res = res;
         try {
             this.user = Guard.jwt.verify(req.get('Authorization'), Guard.secret);  // All requests, where the user hast to be logged in are send with a JWT in the header
         } catch(err) {
             this.deny(err.message); // Validation of JWT failed, so the request must be aborted;
         }
     }

     isManager () {
         if (!this.user.roles.includes("manager"))
             this.deny("You aren't a Manager");
     }

     deny(err:string = 'Access Denied') {
         this.res.json({
             success: false,
             err: err
         });
         return false;
    }
}
```

*Application*

```
router.get('/deleteCourse/:id', (req, res) => {

    new Guard(req,res).isManager(); //Stop execution if token is invalid or user is not a manager

    // Course will be deleted and terminate with

    res.json({success: true}
})
```

I'm aware of the fact that I could use some if Statements, but I want to avoid that in order to keep the script as clean as possible.

Is there a way my approach could be working or can you offer a better approach?

**Possible solution with one if statement**

```
router.get('/deleteCourse/:id', (req, res) => {

    const guard = new Guard(req,res);

    if (guard.user && guard.isManager() {

        //Continue Execution

    }
})
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, and this looks a lot like JavaScript to me.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Yeah it's Typescript, I never mentioned Java

Comment: _"I'm aware of the fact that I could use some if Statements, but I want to avoid that in order to keep the script as clean as possible. 
Is there a way my approach could be working or can you offer a better approach?"_ What do you mean by "clean" and "better"? What is issue with using `if` statement if using the same will resolve inquiry?

Comment: Checking if a client sent a valid token by creating an instance of `Guard` followed by any other methods, so I don't need to pack each validation in an  if statement @guest271314

Comment: @MichaelCool Not following what you mean? The original Question stated that using an `if` condition could resolve Question. Is that not the case?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, but I'm wondering if there is something like PHP's `exit()` in JS

Comment: Yes, there is something similar to PHP's `exit()` in node - `process.exit()`. But every PHP script runs in its own thread, whereas with node, if you call `process.exit()`, it shuts down the entire server.

Comment: @MattBrowne Exactly, that’s why I’m looking for a JS solution

Comment: I was referring to how you originally tagged the question Java (I edited it out). Easy mistake to make, but be careful which tag you use.

Comment: Since you can't just exit, you'll still need an if statement in the route callback after sending the error response, otherwise it will still execute the rest of the code after you send an error using `res.json(...)`. I would do something like `if (new Guard(req, res).authenticate()) ...`

Comment: @MattBrowne Great advice, will do! But I suspect that the possible solution I've added to the question should be the best way

Comment: Cool. BTW I realized that since you're returning JSON, what I wrote earlier about `next()` isn't applicable here (so I edited my comment). Also, a more general answer: express route callbacks are just functions, so they have the same semantics as any function. You can only exit early by either using `return` or `throw`...so if function 1 calls function 2, function 2 can't cause function 1 to exit without an if statement in function 1.